# Changing specific values in a kableExtra table

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I'm looking to change specific values in a `kableExtra` table.

Here is an example. I've created a summary statistics table outputted using `kableExtra`. The statistics are based on the *iris* dataset and I've added in a *Year* variables.

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Year = runif(n = 150, min = 2005, max = 2020) %>% 
           round(digits = 0)) %>% 
  sumtable(out = "kable",
           vars = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Year"),
           summ = c("notNA(x)", "mean(x)", "sd(x)", "min(x)", "max(x)"),
           summ.names = c("Count", "Mean", "St. Dev.", "Min", "Max")) %>% 
  kable_styling()
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

For the last row, the mean and standard deviation are inapplicable, whereas the count, minimum, and maximum have some use.

Thus, I want to change the values for the mean and standard deviation of the row for *Year* to be either *NA* or *-*. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return a dataframe, transform the required entries to `NA` and then style the kable, e.g.

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(vtable)


iris %>% 
  mutate(Year = runif(n = 150, min = 2005, max = 2020) %>% 
           round(digits = 0)) %>% 
  sumtable(out = "return",
           vars = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Year"),
           summ = c("notNA(x)", "mean(x)", "sd(x)", "min(x)", "max(x)"),
           summ.names = c("Count", "Mean", "St. Dev.", "Min", "Max")) %>%
  mutate(Mean = ifelse(Variable == "Year", NA_real_, Mean),
         `St. Dev.` = ifelse(Variable == "Year", NA_real_, `St. Dev.`))  %>%
  kable(digits = 2, caption = "Summary") %>%
  kable_styling()
```

Comment: Great idea! Thanks, Julian.

For anyone else using Julian's code, I also recommend using `case_when` instead of `ifelse` arguments. I personally find  `case_when` to be more intuitive.